# C#- Get Control text that created at runtime

Tags: c#, runtime

How I can get text of a control that was created at runtime?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Top = 50;
    btn.Left = 50;
    btn.Name = "mybtn";
    btn.Text = "My button";
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mybtn.text); // error
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(this.Controls.Find("mybtn")[0].text);`

Comment: Presumably in your actual application the button's text isn't hard coded, it's based on some other type of data.  (If it is hard coded just have both click handlers reference the same `const` string).  Rather than "storing your data in the UI" and having the second click handler reach into the button to get it's data, have it get the data from the underlying source that the button used to determine what it should do.  Without knowing more about your program I can't really give specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var b = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "mybtn");
if (b == null) { return; }

Console.WriteLine(b.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // find mybtn
    Button mybtn = this.Controls.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "mybtn") as Button;
    if (mybtn != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mybtn.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either declare newly created control as a class member(property or field):

```
Button btn ;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn = new Button();
    btn.Top = 50;
    btn.Left = 50;
    btn.Name = "mybtn";
    btn.Text = "My button";
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

**OR**

search it through the form controls:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.Controls.Cast<Control>().Single(p=>p.Name == "mybtn").Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(this.Controls.Find("myBtn", false).FirstOrDefault().Text);
}
```